# How to inject HTML in to a specific div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to inject HTML into a div on a page that I don't have access to the HTML, but can't seem to get the function right.

The HTML structure looks a bit like this:

```
<body class="ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB">
    <div id="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="main" class="container">
            <div id="info">
                <h2 itemprop="name">Product Name</h2>
                <p><span itemprop="price">&pound;55.00</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the JS looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var $body = $(document.body);   
    if (body.attr('class').match(/body.ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB/).length > 0) {
        $('#main .container').prepend("<div id="recommendations"><ul<li>Cross sell 1</li><li>Cross sell 2</li><li>Cross sell 3</li></ul></div>");
    }
});
```

I am green when it comes to JS so I'm, not confident in the above but can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Could some one take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zL8L7zdk/

Comment: your jsfiddle doesn't have that js in it

Comment: Just updated it - sorry

Comment: are you trying to use regex to find the body element you're looking for? do you really have more than one `body` element on the page?

Comment: The problem is with your regex. You should consider more simple ways to query for an element with jQuery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three things.

1) `body` is not defined. You defined `$body`
2) Your RegEx does not evaluate correctly.

`"ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB".match(/body.ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB/);` returns `null`.

If you want to make sure that the body has all those classes, do this instead:

`$body.is(".ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB")`

This will match those classes in no specific order.

3) You used double-quotes inside a double-quote string. Replace instances of `"` with `'` inside the HTML string.

Comment: Thanks - I changed to this and it worked. Strangely, taking the double quotes out and replacing with single broke it. Leaving as is worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the line:

```
$('#main .container').prepend("<div id="recommendations"><ul<li>Cross sell 1</li><li>Cross sell 2</li><li>Cross sell 3</li></ul></div>");
```

Try using 'single' instead of "double" quotes around the html content, 
Selector for the container should have no space, also a typo in the opening ul tag

Try it like this:

```
$('#main.container').prepend('<div id="recommendations"><ul><li>Cross sell 1</li><li>Cross sell 2</li><li>Cross sell 3</li></ul></div>');
```

Comment: Also, `#main .container` matches no element, there is one space too much. `#main.container` would do.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your code.

`var body` should be `var $body`

`<div id="recommendations">` should be `<div id='recommendations'>`

You have to use single quotes inside double quotes or vice versa.

Your match is also wrong and you don't need to check a length:

`/ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB/`

https://jsfiddle.net/zL8L7zdk/2/

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var $body = $(document.body);   
      if ($body.attr('class').match(/ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB/)) {
    $('.container').append("<div id='recommendations'><ul<li>Cross sell 1</li><li>Cross sell 2</li><li>Cross sell 3</li></ul></div>");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

First, your regular expression doesn't work. Try using jQuery `is()` instead.

```
if ($('body').is(".ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB") {
```

Second, your HTML string gets broken by the conflicting double quotes. Use single quotes `''` to wrap the HTML so that the double quotes `""` in the attributes don't break the string.

```
$('#main .container').prepend('<div id="recommendations"><ul<li>Cross sell 1</li><li>Cross sell 2</li><li>Cross sell 3</li></ul></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need to use a regex expression as using a jquery selector will do the same thing. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if ($("body.ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB").length > 0) {
        $('#main.container').prepend('<div id="recommendations"><ul><li>Cross sell 1</li><li>Cross sell 2</li><li>Cross sell 3</li></ul></div>');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zL8L7zdk/6/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are using jquery or not.

But if you do follow this example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $(".ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB").append('<div id="recommendations"><ul<li>Cross sell 1</li><li>Cross sell 2</li><li>Cross sell 3</li></ul></div>');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Menda0/zL8L7zdk/10/

You need to select a DOM object using selectors.
Here is some read about this topic http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp